# copying folder content

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm writing a batch script and need to copy the content of a certain folder to another folder.

For example I have the folder

```
source/
  file1.txt 
  file2.txt 
  file3.txt
```

and I have files in a destination folder. How do I copy the contents of `source` into `destination` so the final destination would look like this

```
destination/
  existing1.txt
  existing2.txt
  file1.txt 
  file2.txt 
  file3.txt
```

I tried xcopy but can't quite get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use wildcards:

```
xcopy source\*.* destination\*.*
```

Comment: I'd rather use xcopy, because it copies folders too.

Answer (score 1):

Using wildcards as mentioned above you can easily copy the contents from one file to another.

For example if your source folder and destination folder are on your desktop you could have the following: (substituting the "YOURNAME" with your PC or laptop's name)

@echo off > *.txt

setLocal DisableDelayedExpansion

set dest="C:\Documents and Settings\YOURNAME\Desktop\destination"

xcopy "C:\Documents and Settings\YOURNAME\Desktop\source\*.txt" %dest% /E /I